# Как обработать событие мыши на осях графика matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouse-event, mousewheel

Мне нужно обработать событие колеса мыши на осях графика, которые показаны красным цветом на рисунке. И при этом нужно определить, на какой оси - вертикальной или горизонтальной - произошло это событие.

В основном везде написано, что нужно использовать на атрибуте `canvas` графика метод `mpl_connect`. Я так и сделал и обнаружил, что при нахождении указателя мыши над указанными областями только значения `x` и `y` параметра `event` имеют определённое значение (остальные имеют значение `None`). Атрибут `inaxes` имеет определённое значение только когда указатель мыши находится над розовой областью. Так что я не знаю, как таким способом можно определить, над какой осью произошло событие.

Конечно, я мог бы попытаться рассчитать координаты этих осей и определять место возникновения события по атрибутам `xy`, но убеждён, что эти оси сами по себе являются объектами, а значит, могут сами устанавливать обработчики событий. Только как до них достучаться?

[image: Plot with areas]

```
def zoom(event)
    print(event)

p, ax = plt.subplots()
t = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
v = [3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6]
plt.plot(t, v)
p.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', zoom)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75691921/5767249

Comment: не совсем понятна ваша цель. Вы же можете работать с объектами slider напрямую, если вам так нужно. https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html

Comment: @strawdog, нет, слайдеры будут сдвигать график влево-вправо вверх-вниз, а колесо будет менять масштаб каждой оси. Мне показалось, что это будет удобнее, чем использовать 4 слайдера.

Comment: Нашёл метод [matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_position](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_position.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-get-position), чтобы понять, где находится график на рисунке и сравнивать с координатами мыши, но пока не могу понять, как преобразовать `Bbox` в абсолютные координаты.

Comment: у BBox есть метод get_points(), он дает вложенный массив numpy, в котором в первом подмассиве будут как раз начальные x и y этого самого Axes.

Comment: Может, сделаете проще: обычный скролл мышью - изменение масштаба по одной оси, а скролл+зажатый Ctrl, например - изменение масштаба по другой оси?

Comment: @strawdog, этот метод мне выдал относительные координаты: `array([[0.2 , 0.2 ], [0.9 , 0.88]])`. А атрибуты `x`, `y` объекта `event` выражают абсолютные координаты в пикселях от левого нижнего угла окна графика.

Comment: @strawdog, спасибо за предложение, если не найду способа решить вопрос, то так и сделаю.